# WPF/C#: Trigger click event from the Storyboard

Tags: wpf, triggers, storyboard, expression-blend

Is it possible to trigger the click event from a `Storyboard` using Expression Blend 4?

I am trying to trigger click events based from the duration I set inside the Storyboard.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="TriggerButtonClick">
 ... something here
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: AFAIK, You can't do that. Why do you want to do that? May be there us a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can only launch Animations inside Storyboards, in Blend or Visual Studio.